# Is this a good use of a nested class?

Tags: java

I have a class called BarGraph. It has a public static nested class BarGraphData. The BarGraph class has an add method that takes BarGraphData. Is this a good idea to have the data class nested?

Thanks

Comment: You could just name it `Data` since when you call it from outside it will have to be `BarGraph.Data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, nesting of static classes doesnt really matter that much after your code is compiled. I would go with whatever makes you feel like you can use it in a logical way when writing your bargraph.

If you want to define a relation you can also devide your classes into packages.